# Add Multiple wallet addresses in the whiteListMintSetting using candy machine v2

Tags: solana, metaplex, anchor-solana, candy-machine, solana-program-library

I am working on a project where I want to pass multiple address as whitelist which can mint before the public mint, I want to know how can I pass multiple addresses in whitelListMintSetting, like
"whitelistMintSettings": {
"mode" : { "burnEveryTime": true },
"mint" : ["7nE1GmnMmDKiycFkpHF7mKtxt356FQzVonZqBWsTWZNf","7nE1GmnMmDKiycFkpHF7mKtxt356FQzVonZqBWsTWZNf","7nE1GmnMmDKiycFkpHF7mKtxt356FQzVonZqBWsTWZNf"],
"presale" : true,
"discountPrice" : null
},

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to add multiple whitelist mints to the config.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Airdrop everyone the same token
2. Divide the mint time into multiple slots and update the config accordingly. E.g. allow mint 1 to mint from 9 AM to 10 AM, update the candy machine config to allow mint 2 to mint from 10 AM to 11 AM etc.

Comment: so how can I iterate on  config file? and how to specify only these account holders can mint in the presale and public mint cannot be allowed in presale?

Comment: I have 50 whitelist addresses and I just want in the presale only these addresses can mint, can you please guide me how is this possible?

Comment: send those 50 addresses a WL token and add its address to your config.
You can NOT whitelist wallets with candy machine.

Answer (score 0):

> maybe you should use tokens and not wallet based, so you can just add the token mint address and expect it to burn after each mint or create a script for all the wallet addresses.